# Yii2 выборка gridview с условием dropdownlist

Tags: php, yii2

Yii2 я изучаю недавно, и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Суть задачи: вывести всех студентов специальности. ID специальности получаю так:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'ID_academic_direction')->dropDownList($arrAca,['prompt'=>'Специальность',
    'onchange'=>'$.post("/enrollee/enrollee/lists?ID='.'"+$(this).val(),function (data){
     $("select#enrollee-index").html(data);
     });',]) ?>
```

и передаю в action:

```
public function actionLists($ID) {
    $countEnrollee=Enrollee::find()
        ->where(['ID_academic_direction'=>$ID])
        ->count();
    if($countEnrollee>0){
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Enrollee::find()
            ->where(['ID_academic_direction'=>$ID ])
            ->orderBy('all_score DESC'),
        ]);
    } else {
        echo "<option>Пусто</option>";
    }

    return $this->render('update', [
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

При вызове action пишет :"Не найден обязательный параметр ID"

Comment: а действительно ли вы передаете в actionLists переменную $ID ?

Comment: Покажите как выглядит от отрендеринная страница, там где выводите поле ID_academic_direction